# What is the recommended way to interact with smart contracts in Meteor?

Tags: solidity, meteor

I have a meteor web application and want to interact with my smart contracts. Most of the data are stored in the Meteor MongoDB. I only store a hash of the data on the blockchain. Where should I the write to the contract? Is it recommended to do it on the server or on the client side?